# Missing line in a color box

Tags: tcolorbox

I'm creating boxes for theorems. My code is the following:

```
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{pro}[2][]{colframe=blue,colback=white,rightrule=0pt,
  toprule=3pt,title={Proposition \thetcbcounter\ #2},coltitle={black},sharp corners,
  frame style={left color=black,right color=black},
  #1}

\begin{document}

\begin{pro}{}
test
\end{pro}

\end{document}
```

How I can put the missing line on the right?

Comment: you have specified `rightrule=0pt,`

Comment: How can I control the vertical space between the top of the blue box and the "Proposition" word, and between the button of the blue box and the word "Proposition"?

Comment: `/bottomtitle=⟨length⟩`  and `/toptitle=⟨length⟩ `